# Facebook comments in iOS UIWebView

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, uiwebview

I'm loading a URL from my own web site into a UIWebView in an iPhone app. This page has the Facebook Comments social plugin enabled. It was working beautifully two weeks ago, using the mobile friendly version of Facebook comments. However, a week ago, something changed on Facebook's end. I'm no longer seeing the mobile friendly version, and it has that awful "Comment Using" drop down that lets you log in via Facebook, Yahoo, AOL, or Hotmail, which is clearly meant for a desktop/mouse setup.

Does anyone know of a way to get the mobile friendly markup in this scenario?

I already tried using Facebook's iOS SDK for reading & posting comments, but your Facebook app has to be "white listed" before you're able to post comments using the Graph API. It turns out that only ONE app is white listed...something called "Causes." Ugh.

Thanks!

Comment: I should note that the Reply link doesn't work either in this UIWebView for Facebook comments. If you tap it once, it becomes underlined. Then when you tap it a second time, the keyboard slides up and back down immediately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah ha! Facebook **finally** fixed this problem:

https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-media/bringing-facebook-comments-to-mobile/306485919386904

Comment: Please accept your own answer. It helps people when they are searching.

Answer (score -1):

Have you updated your facebook API, as it has been changed from 1st October.

Check Out this [link](http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/)

Comment: Yes, I have, but that's irrelevant since I'm using a web view with the Facebook social plugin on my own web site, within the HTML markup.

Comment: sanchitsingh, you honestly have a UIWebView that uses the Facebook Comments Social Plugin that receives the mobile-friendly markup from FB? That is, you see a built-in, blue, web-based nav bar with a white back button and no tiny "Comment Using" drop-down that makes you log in via FB, Yahoo, AOL, or Hotmail before leaving a comment? I'd like to see a screen shot. Thanks.